# sorting individual columns in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort a cvs file to have highest to lowest values for each individual column but when I try my code it sorts the first column but takes the values of the remaining rows with it  so for example this is the excel file and it would sort column A but won't sort the rest from highest to lowest and will just take the corresponding row which is not what I want cause for column B the highest value is 98.

```
import pandas as pd
 
bus1_data = pd.read_csv("p1Bus1Data.csv",header=None)


bus1_data.rename(columns={0: 'quantity bids', 1: 'price of bids', 2: 'quantity of offers', 3: 'price of offers'}, inplace=True)
bus1_data.to_csv('test_with_col.csv', index=False)

bus2_data = pd.read_csv("p1Bus2Data.csv",header=None)

bus2_data.rename(columns={0: 'quantity bids', 1: 'price of bids', 2: 'quantity of offers', 3: 'price of offers'}, inplace=True)
bus2_data.to_csv('test_with_col.csv', index=False)

sorted_bus1_data = bus1_data.sort_values(['quantity bids','price of bids','quantity of offers','price of offers'], ascending=[False,False,False,False])
sorted_bus1_data.to_csv('p1Bus1Data_sorted.csv', index=False)

sorted_bus2_data = bus2_data.sort_values(by=["quantity bids", "price of bids", "quantity of offers", "price of offers"],ascending=[False,False,False,False])
sorted_bus2_data.to_csv('p1Bus2Data_sorted.csv', index=False)

print(sorted_bus1_data.head())

print(sorted_bus2_data.head())
```

Results I got:

[image: Results I got]

Excel i'm using with highlights:

[image: Excel i'm using with highlights]

Thank you

Comment: read notice: we need [mre] to answer your question. make minimal example in text table (like 5rows X 3 columns) and provide deired output of input in text table

Comment: Make sure you include a reproducible example if you can. It's helpful.

Comment: `df[:] = np.sort(df.values)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah looks like the way you're using `sort_values` sorts the entire `DataFrame` based on the first column ('quantity bids'). Subsequent columns get rearranged according to the initial sort, not sorted independently.

Have a think about sorting each column individually in descending order. Maybe iterate through the columns and apply sorting to each one

```
Python
import pandas as pd

# ... (your existing code to load data)

def sort_columns_independently(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].sort_values(ascending=False).values  # Notice the '.values'
    return df

sorted_bus1_data = sort_columns_independently(bus1_data.copy())  # Create a copy to avoid modifying the original
sorted_bus2_data = sort_columns_independently(bus2_data.copy())

# ... (save to CSV and print)
```

If you use the function `sort_columns_independently` to take a `DataFrame` as input, you can iterate through each column, sort it in descending order, and then reassigns the sorted values back to the column using `.values`. Then use `.copy()` to prevent modifications to your original `bus1_data` and `bus2_data` `DataFrames`. Woot.

Answer (score 2):

**Example Code**

We need [a minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in text or code to help you. This time, I will example one for you.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'col1': [10, 30, 20, 40], 'col2': [60, 90, 10, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df:

```
   col1  col2
0    10    60
1    30    90
2    20    10
3    40    20
```

---

**Code**

use `np.sort`

```
import numpy as np
out = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=0)[::-1], columns=df.columns)
```

out

```
   col1  col2
0    40    90
1    30    60
2    20    20
3    10    10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

bus1_data = pd.read_csv("p1Bus1Data.csv",header=None)
bus2_data = pd.read_csv("p1Bus2Data.csv",header=None)

bus1_data.rename(columns={0: 'quantity bids', 1: 'price of bids', 2: 'quantity of offers', 3: 'price of offers'}, inplace=True)
bus2_data.rename(columns={0: 'quantity bids', 1: 'price of bids', 2: 'quantity of offers', 3: 'price of offers'}, inplace=True)

sorted_bus1_data = bus1_data.sort_values(['quantity bids','price of bids','quantity of offers','price of offers'], ascending=[False,False,False,False])
sorted_bus1_data.to_csv('p1Bus1Data_sorted.csv', index=False)

sorted_bus2_data = bus2_data.sort_values(by=["quantity bids", "price of bids", "quantity of offers", "price of offers"],ascending=[False,False,False,False])
sorted_bus2_data.to_csv('p1Bus2Data_sorted.csv', index=False)

print(sorted_bus1_data.head())
print(sorted_bus2_data.head())
```